# Google Oauth2 Client Login fails with HTTP 403

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-python-client, google-apps-marketplace

We are using Google OAuth2 client login for user authentication, The Google Project is linked with a Google Apps Marketplace Application

```
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
                        client_id    = config['CLIENT_ID'],
                        client_secret= config['CLIENT_SECRET'],
                        scope        = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                        redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
                        access_type  = 'online',
                        state        = json.dumps(self.request.arguments))
    auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    self.redirect(auth_uri)
```

Users are occasionally experiencing a HTTP 403 when they are redirected to the `auth_uri`.

I checked all the quota limits, and they are not being exceeded.

How do I resolve this ?

Edit: the 403 is coming on `http://accounts.google.com/....`

Edit here is a screenshot 
[image]

Comment: The 403 is coming from your server or from Google?

Comment: @abraham Its coming on Google Servers (Ocassionally no specific pattern)